# Angular fire app losing authstate upon refreshing the page

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Hi all I am working on a sharing app with angular and firebase and I have encountered a problem that I have 1. Never encountered before 2. Tried solutions from stack overflow to no avail. I am implementing an auth guard into my app so that certain pages can only be viewed by authenticated users.
Here is my sign in directive code:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appGoogleSignin]',
})
export class GoogleSigninDirective {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  onclick() {
    this.afAuth
      .setPersistence(firebase.default.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
      .then(() => {
        this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(
          new firebase.default.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
        );
      });
  }
}
```

Here is my authguard code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  UrlTree,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SnackService } from '../services/snack.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private snack: SnackService) {}

  async canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = await this.afAuth.currentUser;
    const isLoggedIn = !!user;
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.snack.authError();
    }

    return isLoggedIn;
  }
}
```

And here is my implementation of the auth guard:

```
    path: 'upload',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./upload/upload.module').then((m) => m.UploadModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
```

I have tried multiple solutions on stack overflow including setting the persistence state to both session and local. None have worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this.afAuth.currentUser` value is refreshed asynchronously when you load the page. So by the time your code accesses `this.afAuth.currentUser` it probably hasn't been set yet.

Instead of accessing the `this.afAuth.currentUser` value synchronously, observe the `auth.user` stream to make sure you are always reacting to the latest authentication state. See also the first code sample in [Getting started with Firebase Authentication](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md).

Comment: Ah yes instead of saying ```this.afAuth.currentUser```  i did ```this.afAuth.user.subscribe()``` and that worked! Thank you